# SQL Server Logon Trigger Error after server restart

Tags: sql-server, logon-trigger

I have a logon trigger running that is executing as another user to log connection details.  It works totally fine without issue except right after a server reboot.  At that point, I have to connect to the server via the DAC and disable it.  Then I can just enable it again and everything is fine.

The error I see in the server logs says:

> The connection has been dropped because the principal that opened it
> subsequently assumed a new security context, and then tried to reset
> the connection under its impersonated security context. This scenario
> is not supported.

I'm not sure why it would only run into this issue right after a reboot.  Any idea what the issue might be?

```
create trigger [LogonAudit]
on all server with execute as 'svc_LogDBUser'
for logon
as
begin

begin try

declare @LogonTriggerData xml
       ,@SPID varchar(50)
       ,@EventType varchar(50)
       ,@LoginTime datetime
       ,@UserName varchar(50)
       ,@LoginName varchar(50)
       ,@LoginType varchar(50)
       ,@ServerName varchar(50)
       ,@HostName varchar(50)
       ,@ClientHost varchar(50)
       ,@AppName varchar(500)

set @LogonTriggerData = eventdata()

set @SPID = @@spid
set @EventType = @LogonTriggerData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'sysname')
set @LoginTime = @LogonTriggerData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/PostTime)[1]', 'datetime')
set @UserName = original_login()
set @LoginName = @LogonTriggerData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
set @LoginType = @LogonTriggerData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginType)[1]', 'sysname')
set @ServerName = @LogonTriggerData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ServerName)[1]', 'nvarchar(257)')
set @ClientHost = @LogonTriggerData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ClientHost)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
set @HostName = host_name()
set @AppName = app_name()

insert into LogDB.dbo.LogonAudit
    (SPID
    ,EventType
    ,LoginTime
    ,UserName
    ,LoginName
    ,LoginType
    ,ServerName
    ,HostName
    ,ClientHost
    ,AppName)
values
(@SPID, @EventType, @LoginTime, @UserName, @LoginName, @LoginType, @ServerName, @HostName, @ClientHost, @AppName)

    end try

begin catch

--don't worry about it

end catch

end
go
```

Comment: Can you share the content of the trigger? it might be the cause of the error.

Comment: @Ronaldo - I added a screenshot of the trigger code.

Comment: @BarryFuhrmann, it's best to post code as formatted text (CTRL-K) rather than as an image.

Comment: Drop the "with execute as ..." clause and then using a database that is not master for these case of tracking will have some trouble, because when the logging is done, the logDB database is probably not yet recovered !